# Trouble with authorization using client_credentials Azure AD Graph API

Tags: azure, active-directory, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use OAuth `client_credentials` with <del>Windows</del> Microsoft Azure. I can successfully generate an `access_token` but get when I try and access `https://graph.windows.net/mydomain.com/users?api-version=2013-04-05` I get `403 Forbidden`.

What am I doing wrong? I think I'm not requestion a sufficiently authorized `access_token` but I cannot find/guess other `resource` or params to add.

**My current flow**

Request

```
> POST /mydomain.com/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: login.windows.net
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id={client_id}
&client_secret={client_secret}
&resource=https://graph.windows.net
```

Response

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
{
  "access_token": "<string>",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": "<seconds>",
  "expires_on": "<timestamp>",
  "resource": "https://graph.windows.net"
}
```

Request

```
> GET /mydomain.com/users
>   ?api-version=2013-04-05 HTTP/1.1
> Host: graph.windows.net
> Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
```

Response

```
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": {
        "lang": "en",
        "value": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I get 403 Unauthorized if I miss out or mess with the `{access_token}`.

Comment: Is this for a web application or a native client application? Also, what do you have selected in the "permissions to other applications" drop-downs in the portal?

Comment: @SeanOsterberg brilliant that worked. Submit an answer proper and I'll accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment, you need to make sure that you've selected the proper permissions from the "permissions to other applications" drop-down in the portal, otherwise access won't be granted. See [this page in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn132599.aspx#BKMK_Updating) for more information.