# How to use Azure AD Graph API access for service principals?

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, adal4j

I have a working Azure AD/Azure daemon application using adal4j that uses user/password authentication.  Due to issues with ADFS, I wish to also be able to authenticate using a service principal (client ID/secret).  This seems to work fine for the Azure (non-AD) portion of the app, as the SP roles can be defined for the subscriptions in question, however for the Azure AD part, I get:

`response code 403, error: Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.`

...this occurs on the first call to the Graph API - I get valid tokens from AuthenticationContext.acquireToken() using the https://graph.windows.net scope.

My account is an Owner in the directory.  I've tried using the "Grant Permissions" button on the app, and have also tried fabricating a consent URL (which works) and using that to consent to the app having the necessary privileges in the directory.  Neither seems to affect this.

The app is a Native app, as it is a daemon/service app, so can't participate in OAuth2 consent.

How does one access the Azure AD Graph API using a SP to authenticate?  As a reminder, unchanged, the app works with (non-ADFS) user/password, and the SP works with the Azure API, just not Azure AD Graph API.

Thanks...

P.S.  I've also tried this with the Azure Graph API, which Microsoft now recommends instead of the Azure AD Graph API.  Same result, and similarly works with user/password creds.

Amending this to kind of take adal4j out of the picture - this seems to be more of a generic Azure AD problem.  Here's an example of the problem, using curl:

Client credentials token request:

```
curl --request POST "https://login.windows.net/367cxxxx41e5/oauth2/token" --data-urlencode "resource=https://graph.windows.net" --data-urlencode "client_id=9d83yyyy08cd" --data-urlencode "grant_type=client_credentials" --data-urlencode "client_secret=secret"
```

Client credentials token response:

```
{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":"3599","ext_expires_in":"0","expires_on":"1491486990","not_before":"1491483090","resource":"https://graph.windows.net","access_token":"eyJ0zzzz2zVA"}
```

Azure AD REST query using client credentials token:

```
curl "https://graph.windows.net/367cxxxx41e5/tenantDetails" --header "Authorization: eyJ0xxxx2zVA" --header "Accept: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata" --header "api-version: 1.6"
```

Azure AD REST response using client credentials token:

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}}}
```

Now, contrast that with (note the same tenant ID/app ID):

Password credentials token request:

```
curl --request POST "https://login.windows.net/367cxxxx41e5/oauth2/token" --data-urlencode "resource=https://graph.windows.net" --data-urlencode "client_id=9d83yyyy08cd" --data-urlencode "grant_type=password" --data-urlencode "username=bozo@clown.com" --data-urlencode "password=password"
```

Password credentials token response:

```
{"token_type":"Bearer","scope":"Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.Read.All Group.Read.All Member.Read.Hidden User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All","expires_in":"3599","ext_expires_in":"0","expires_on":"1491489157","not_before":"1491485257","resource":"https://graph.windows.net","access_token":"eyJ0zzzz0EXQ","refresh_token":"AQABzzzzAgAA"}
```

Azure AD REST query using password credentials token:

```
curl "https://graph.windows.net/367cxxxx41e5/tenantDetails" --header "Authorization: eyJ0xxxx0EXQ" --header "Accept: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata" --header "api-version: 1.6"
```

Azure AD REST response using password credentials token:

```
{"odata.metadata":"https://graph.windows.net/367cxxxx41e5/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.TenantDetail","value":[{"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.TenantDetail","objectType":"Company","objectId":"367cxxxx41e5","deletionTimestamp":null,"assignedPlans":[{"assignedTimestamp":"2017-02-24T03:25:33Z","capabilityStatus":"Enabled","service":"SharePoint","servicePlanId":"e95byyyyc014"},...
```

My suspicion at this point is that the SP, created by default by Azure AD when the app was created, doesn't include the necessary permissions.  I'll try creating a new SP with the rights specified.  Examples of this abound, but all are focused on the target app being some mythical LOB app, not Azure AD.  And, as seems usual with the half-baked portal, the CLI must be used to do this.

```
</snark>
```

Also, I've verified that anyone with Reader role should be able to execute that query.  I've added both Contributer and Owner to the SP, with no effect.

Also also, FWIW, I've verified that the SP has, in theory, the Azure AD (and other) permissions I entered in the portal.  I think.

```
    PS C:\> Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOAuth2PermissionGrant -objectid 'a9f9xxxx5377'|format-list -property consenttype,resourceid,scope

ConsentType : AllPrincipals
ResourceId  : c569xxxxe7f0
Scope       : Member.Read.Hidden User.Read User.ReadBasic.All User.Read.All Group.Read.All Directory.Read.All
              Directory.AccessAsUser.All

ConsentType : AllPrincipals
ResourceId  : 3318xxxx66a5
Scope       : user_impersonation

ConsentType : AllPrincipals
ResourceId  : 8c0fxxxx4198
Scope       : User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All Group.Read.All Directory.Read.All Directory.AccessAsUser.All User.Read

PS C:\> get-azureadobjectbyobjectid -objectids 'c569xxxxe7f0','3318xxxx66a5','8c0fxxxx4198'

 ObjectId     AppId                                DisplayName
--------     -----                                -----------
8c0fxxxx4198 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 Microsoft Graph
3318xxxx66a5 797f4846-ba00-4fd7-ba43-dac1f8f63013 Windows Azure Service Management API
c569xxxxe7f0 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory
```

Comment: Hi, did you try using the new Apps Registration (preview) on the portal. It lists down the SPs you already have and allows you to add Microsoft Graph API permissions but you need to be an administrator to consent to those - try the steps here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, per my experience, I think the issue was caused by two reasons.

1. Not add api access of `Windows Azure Active Directory (Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory)` in the `Required permissions` tab of your registed application in Azure AD on Azure portal as below and select the related permissions.

[image]

As references, you can refer to the other SO thread [Trouble with authorization using client_credentials Azure AD Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965288/trouble-with-authorization-using-client-credentials-azure-ad-graph-api) or the offical document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications#BKMK_Updating) and a helpful [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2016/10/21/using-the-azure-arm-rest-apin-get-access-token/).

2. Not assign `Contributor` for this service principal. You need to run the powershell command below to do this.

   ```
   New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Contributor -ServicePrincipalName 'applicationID'
   ```

   Or you can also refer to my answer for another SO thread [Cannot list image publishers from Azure java SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35009350/cannot-list-image-publishers-from-azure-java-sdk/35016433#35016433) to do this via Azure CLI or just on Azure portal.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Peter Pan: Thanks for the response.  Please see my expanded post, including curl examples of goodness/badness.  As I mention, I don't think the problem is the rights as enumerated in the portal, but rather the rights assigned to the SP (not available in the portal, sadly).  I've had those from the beginning.  I suspect the #2 part of your answer is on target.

Comment: Peter Pan: Sorry - no joy.  I tried adding both Contributer and Owner roles (separately), and still receive the same error.

RoleAssignmentId   : /subscriptions/ff34xxxx65df/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/0c7exxxxaa2b
Scope              : /subscriptions/ff34xxxx65df
DisplayName        : Test Azure AD Client ID
SignInName         :
RoleDefinitionName : Owner
RoleDefinitionId   : 8e3axxxxb635
ObjectId           : a9f9xxxx5377
ObjectType         : ServicePrincipal

Comment: Peter Pan: One thing I do wonder about is the scope of the SP role.  Using New-AzureRmRoleAssignment, the scope has to be a subscription.  Since the directory isn't really associated with a subscription, how does one tell it which scope to use?  If you look at the good user token response, it includes the scopes as defined to the app.  Those scopes are rejected when I try to add them.  My experience so far with the Azure AD subscriptions is that they can't be used for role assignment directly.  At least the Azure CLI (not PowerShell) rejects those subscriptions when trying to do RBAC stuff.